# Is there a solution for Canonical Correlation Analysis on large sparse matrices?

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, sparse, canonical-correlation, numerics

I'm trying to run CCA over two views which are sparse matrices. The two views are very high dimensional (e.g. 300k, 400k) with 1m samples.

CCA needs the input views to be zero mean but I won't be able to do that on the views because it will densify the matrices.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Note: currently I'm using Deep CCA (Andrew, 2013) to address this challenge but it has a lot of hyperparameters and tuning them given my limited resources is difficult.

Comment: I am curious about this. What did you end up doing?

Comment: used deep cca, the deep side reduces the dimensionality. you can find various implementations on github.